# Scrim not overlaying a status bar while showing a modal bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-view

I have an issue on a device with android 13, where the status bar is not overlaid by the scrim when a modal bottom sheet is showing. Now, the same app works as expected in an emulator with android 7.1.1. The image below shows the erroneous behaviour.

[image: Screenshot of status bar while a modal bottom sheet is expanded]

As seen in the image the status bar color remains as white, which is not the desired outcome.

Some of the solutions I have tried include setting the status bar background as transparent in the `bottomSheetDialogTheme`. My bottom sheet dialog theme overides the `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog`.

Now question is, how do I make the scrim overlay the status bar?